# Python API code to get users and user details from sophos UTM 9

Tags: python

I was trying to get the user details with in READONLY group

My Code

```
NETWORK_GROUP = "READONLY"
NETWORK_GROUP_MEMBERS = "username"
def main():
    try:
       URL = ("https://XXXXXX.com:6789/api/objects/network/group/")
       headers={
         'content_type': 'application/json'
       }
       obj = {"name":NETWORK_GROUP,"members":NETWORK_GROUP_MEMBERS}
       response = requests.get(URL, verify=False, headers = headers, json=obj, auth=('username', 'password')).content.decode("utf-8")
       print(response)
       time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Issue:
Not getting any output just blank []  output or else it is showing <Response [200]> success code but i need user names and details of them

Answer (score 0):

Tried with this url and got resolved!!
url = (API_ENDPOINT + "/objects/aaa/group/")